# flask application "isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: flask, mod-wsgi

I have a domain in which I have successfully launched 7 flask applications. I signed up for another domain. I am trying to launch one application and I am getting:

```
 The page isn’t redirecting properly
 
 An error occurred during a connection to xyzzy.com.

 This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I have this in my xyzzy.com-le-ssl.conf file:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess xyzzy threads=2 user=ray python-home=/home/ray/xyzzy/.venv home=/home/ray/xyzzy
    WSGIScriptAlias /xyzzy /home/ray/xyzzy/xyzzy.py
    <Directory /home/ray/xyzzy/>
            WSGIProcessGroup xyzzy
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I am seeing this in the apache error log. What the heck?

```
 a82ac0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82ac0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a72330a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82aa0a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /xyzzy/
 a82a80a0/initial] pass through /xyzzy/
```